# Stopping/pausing the BJQS slideshow using jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, vimeo, bjqs

I have made a video slideshow using [BJQS](http://www.basic-slider.com/). The videos are embedded as `<iframe>`s and sourced from Vimeo. The slideshow is working fine, but, whenever I play a video, the slideshow carries on rotating, i.e. the video plays for a few seconds but then fades into the next video in the list.

Can anyone suggest how to go about implementing a function to add to BJQS that pauses the slideshow? I am using the Vimeo API so have events available such as 'on video start' and 'on video finish' so do not seek help with this - just pausing (which will fire when the video starts) and resuming (firing on video finish) the slideshow.

In the BJQS source there is a function for pausing the slideshow 'on hovering' and then resuming the slideshow when hover is lost, which works with the Vimeo videos, but all my attempts to harness this have failed.

I am relatively new to jQuery and would appreciate any advice.

Also, if you know of any similar lightweight jQuery slideshows with the ability to pause via an event call built-in, I am willing to consider converting, since a slideshow without this functionality is useless for my scenario.

Comment: In BJQS I saw such option: `automatic : true` what means that slides automaticaly change slides. I don't know, but try to chage this option to false when video is playing.

Comment: Provide a fiddle if you can

Comment: @Epsil0neR I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. This option only works on page load.

Comment: @verbumSapienti then use another plugin, because this doesn't have manipulation of him on runtime. Or try to look at source code and find 'private' members which sets automatic to true/false and try to make them 'public' to access them from outer code. Of course if licence allowes that hack.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you requested to use BJQS but they don't support any events on their plugin and I tried to add the support you were looking for but I don't have that much time to do it. Instead of using that plugin how about using cycle?

There is a sample on fiddle (not mine)

http://jsfiddle.net/ezrafree/hrX2j/

Code is similar to bjqs:

```
$('#container').cycle({
    /* cycle options */
    fx:      'scrollHorz',
    prev:    '#prev',
    next:    '#next',
    timeout:  0,
    after: function() {
        $('#container iframe').attr('src', '');
        var theSource = $(this).find('iframe').attr('alt');
        console.log('theSource:before', theSource);
        $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', theSource);
    }
});
```

they use VIMEO, YOUTUBE and also some static content. You can customize it to your needs and make it look exactly like bjqs and more http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23

Let us know if you need more help customizing this plugin or if you can't change the plugin.